# api to get the lanugage of an wordpress define('WPLANG', '');

Tags: wordpress

is there is any way to get the language of the word press that is installed . i am creating  an plugin i need to detect the language at which thay have installed probably define('WPLANG', '')`;  this value..

Answer (score 2):

Possibly this?: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale